# Question of style in Carl Schurz’s “Lebenserinnerungen”

Tags: style, history

Is this style of [Schurz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Schurz) (who lived in the 19th century) still common in modern writing? Here is an example:

> … so ließ ich bei dieser Veranlassung meine Ansichten über die dem deutschen Volke nach so heldenmütigen Anstrengungen gewordene Behandlung und meine Hoffnung auf eine nationale Regeneration des deutschen Vaterlandes freimütig aus. ([Wikisource](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Schurz_Lebenserinnerungen_b1_s049.jpg))

The noun phrase *die gewordene Behandlung* (if I am reading this correctly) is split by this phrase beginning with *dem deutschen Volke.*  This is but one example of such a construct and I am puzzled at times by its complexity.

There are examples like this in English but it is not usually so grossly composed, for example:

> Here is an example of the to me seemingly overly-complex style in English.

This would probably be re-written as:

> Here is an example of that style in English which to me seems overly complex.

Answer (score 1):

First: I’m not a pro at this, I’m just a German.

Second, you’re right. This sentence seems over-complex and clearly out of date. Some single words wouldn’t be written like this: *Volke* → *Volk*. Using the dative form *Volke* (where *Volk* is the nominative) indicates either the age of the text or some kind of arts (like the lyrics of a song).

And also, in modern German, this one is missing a word which makes all easier … Let’s see. This could be re-written like:

> … so ließ ich bei dieser Veranstaltung freimütig meine Ansichten über die dem deutschen Volk nach so heldenmütigen Anstrengungen zuteil gewordene Behandlung und meine Hoffnung auf eine nationale Regeneration des deutschen Vaterlandes aus.

I have added *zuteil*, which eases understanding the whole sentence (“die Behandlung wird jdm. zuteil”) and took *freimütig* to the beginning, that’s my gut feeling.

Again, I can’t explain the details. I’m just used to it.

Comment: Braucht man da nicht noch einen Sack voll Kommas?

Comment: Wozu ein Sack voll?